# Ruby Require behaviour differing when used with CGI vs command line

Tags: ruby, rubygems, apache2, cgi, rvm

I have a very basic CGI script that's meant to output a bunch of information about the Ruby environment. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

begin

puts <<-EOS
Content-type: text/html

<html>
<body>
EOS

puts "<p>$LOAD_PATH:</p>"
puts "<ul>"
$LOAD_PATH.each {|val| puts "<li>#{val}</li>"}
puts "</ul>"

require 'awesome_print'

puts "<p>RUBY_VERSION: #{RUBY_VERSION}</p>"
puts "<p>$SAFE: #{$SAFE}</p>"

puts "<p>$LOADED_FEATURES:</p>"
puts "<ul>"
$LOADED_FEATURES.each {|key,val| puts "<li>#{key} = #{val}</li>"}
puts "</ul>"

puts "<p>ENV:</p>"
puts "<ul>"
ENV.each {|key,val| puts "<li>#{key} = #{val}</li>"}
puts "</ul>"

rescue Exception => e

puts "<p>EXCEPTION. #{e.message}<br/>#{e.backtrace.join('<br/>')}</p>"

ensure

puts "</body></html>"

end
```

When I run this code from the browser via CGI, through apache2 on localhost, I get:
    EXCEPTION. cannot load such file -- awesome_print

However, when I run from the CLI, it prints the info like it's supposed to.

I've compared the output of `$LOAD_PATH`, and they're identical in both cases, CGI vs CLI.

After some research, I figure the main difference between the CGI and CLI is the user running the service (e.g. www-data for the CGI,  for the CLI), and as a result, the `ENV` available in each case differs. In the CLI case, I have the ENV that is augmented by RVM, providing variables like `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME`. As such, I had to change the Apache `envvars` file to include the RVM modifications to `$PATH`, so that `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` would return the correct version of Ruby (2.1.3 installed with RVM as opposed to 1.8.7 system Ruby).

Other things I've tried:

- `sudo chmod +r -R /home/<user>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3` : `cannot load such file -- awesome_print` (CGI only)
- `sudo chmod 777 -R /home/<user>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3`: `cannot load such file -- awesome_print` (CGI only)
- `ruby <myscript>.rb` before running either `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` or `rvm use 2.1` : `cannot load such file -- awesome_print` (CLI)
- IRB `require`awesome_print`returns`true` in .rvm-enabled CLI
- IRB `$LOAD_PATH` after `rvm use 2.1` returns:

  - "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0",
  - "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux",
  - "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby",
  - "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0",
  - "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux",
  - "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
  - "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0",
  - "/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux"
- **Note: the above output is the same $LOAD_PATH as given as output from both the CGI and CLI**
- `gem which awesome_print` gives `/home/romistrub/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print.rb`
- `$LOAD_PATH << '/home/romistrub/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/'` fixes the `require` issue for CGI, but is an ugly fix, as it **does not work** with gems that have their own dependencies without specifying the paths for all dependencies. E.g., the same `$LOAD_PATH <<` using the `lib` portion of `gem which faye/websocket` *will* allow `require 'faye/websocket'` to load the core gem, but not its dependencies, e.g. `eventmachine`.

Given all of this (potentially superfluous) information, how do these two runtime environments (CGI vs CLI) result in differing `require` behaviour? Can someone direct me to a resource that goes into detail about the behaviour of `require`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently `rubygems` overrides `require`, and as such `require` is actually looking for the `awesome_print` gem using the `ENV['GEM_PATH']` environment variable, and not using `$LOAD_PATH`.

see [rubygems / lib / rubygems / core_ext / kernel_require.rb](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L24)

Because the `GEM_PATH` environment variable was set in bash by RVM through `rvm use 2.1`, and `GEM_PATH` was **not** set in the Apache environment (causing the inconsistent behaviour), I had to add the `GEM_PATH` that was found via the `echo $GEM_PATH` command in the CLI *after `RVM` was loaded* to the Apache environment using a `SetEnv` directive in the Apache configuration file.

My particular situation looked like this:

```
$> echo $GEM_PATH
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
```

then add `SetEnv` line to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`, e.g.:

```
<Directory /var/www/board/demo>
    Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .rb
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews

    SetEnv GEM_PATH /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global

</Directory>
```